# Why does my form disappear in a split second? VBA

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have a sub which instantiates a new form, makes it visible. However the new form lasts only for a very brief moment. This is my code:

```
Private Sub txtProject_ID Click()
       Dim frmReq as Form
       Set frmReq = New Form_Request
       frmReq.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I tried to set break points on this and found out the form becomes visible when I set its visibility to true. However it disappears as soon as the Sub ends.

---

Edit:
How to create multiple instances of the pop up form?

Comment: `frmReq.Show`   ....

Comment: Ok I just tried that and I get an error "Run-time error '2465': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: You need to `Initialize` the user form.

Comment: That's not a userform, it's an Access form. Different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access VBA you use

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Request"
```

If you need to open it invisible you do

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Request", WindowMode:=acHidden
' Initialize stuff while invisible
Forms!Request!foo = "bar"
' show form
Forms!Request.Visible = True
```

---

To open multiple instances (would have helped to mention that in the question) and pass a parameter, create a public initialization function in the form:

```
Public Sub InitForm(ReqId As Long)
   ' e.g.
   Me.Filter = "Request_ID = " & ReqId
   Me.FilterOn = True
   'show me
   Me.Visible = True
End Sub
```

and call it like this (see bottom of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845819.aspx)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
' This variable must be on *module* level!
Dim frmReq as Form

Private Sub txtProject_ID Click()
   Set frmReq = New Form_Request
   Call frmReq.InitForm(Me!txtProject_ID)
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to open it as a popup. So that I can open multiple instances of it as soon as I click a button on the base form.

Comment: Also I would be passing a parameter.

Comment: What does it mean to have a variable on a module level?

Comment: At the top of the module, not inside a sub/function. See edit.

Comment: You know what! I cant thank you enough! You helped me in another question that I had asked earlier as well. Can I have your email address so that you can provide me a good direction for learning VBA. Right now I am just all over the place.

Comment: Now I figured why my form was disappearing initially. That's because it was only alive in the sub and it died as soon as the sub ended.

Answer (score 1):

The variable/object of scope is limited to sub procedure so it needs to be form level.